# Setting cors headers in the client side

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a http long poll request using this example https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-chat/blob/7c474fea5638dc70660fb6029ad891ae92e41801/src/main/webapp/resources/js/chat.js

The server is hosted in port 7555 and browser needs it to be 80. When I run it,  I get the No Access Control Headers error. I do not have the chance to set CORS headers in the server so I need to do this on the client side. I was trying to develop a curl php script, but it does not work (give error 500) Here it is:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:7555/test?list=0");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 7555);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

 $out = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

 echo $out;

 ?>
```

How can I get past CORS from the client side?

Comment: If the owner of the service doesn't want to apply CORS it is most likely because they don't want you accessing the content. To the best of my knowledge this shouldn't be possible

Comment: The owner of the service wants me to create a curl/php proxy script and access through that